# How to open Video in next page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to display only the names of videos in home page, and if I click the particular name of video the video player must be open. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate screen in which you can implement a video player. Use this package [video player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) or [chewie player](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie).You just have to pass either the URL or the Video file of the selected video. You can also pass the asset name if videos are in assets.

```
    import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
    import 'package:chewie/src/chewie_player.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

    class ChewieDemo extends StatefulWidget {
         ChewieDemo({this.url});

          final String url;

        @override
        State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
          return _ChewieDemoState();
          }
      }

    class _ChewieDemoState extends State<ChewieDemo> {

         VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

         ChewieController _chewieController;
      

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
           widget.url);

         _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
         aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
         autoPlay: true,
         looping: true,
 
          );
         }

     @override
     void dispose() {
     _videoPlayerController.dispose();

      _chewieController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
      }

     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(),
    body: 
        Container(
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
         width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
          child: Center(
            child: Chewie(
              controller: _chewieController,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ),
     
  );

    }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you. But it shows white screen when passing video url.

Comment: Try again. I have edited the code. You can give height and width to your video or you can also use Aspect Ratio to decide the size of video.